# Line break at hyphen in source inserts space in output

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, hyphenation

I prefer to wrap lines in my LaTeX source, and my editor will often choose a hyphen as a good place to split the line. Unfortunately, if a hyphenated word doesn't appear in the output file at a line break, then LaTeX will insert a space immediately after the hyphen.

I'm looking for a way to train my editor not to break there. Alternatively, is there a way I can tell LaTeX not to insert a space at a line break if the line ends in a hyphen?

Comment: Train? hmmmmmmmm interesting :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: have you tried with a percent sign `%` after the hyphen as in `text-%[line break in source]text[on next line]`?

Comment: Change editor; if it breaks lines at hyphens it has no use for anything.

Comment: @jfbu a % at the end of the line produces the exact behavior I'm looking for, and seems safe enough for a find-all / replace. Ideally, I'd like to find a "reflow safe" solution (akin to the solution from karlkoeller below) but this is great for now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\myhyphen{-}
\catcode`-=\active
\def-{\myhyphen\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text-
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this works "too well".  if your text includes the phrase "sub- and superscripts", the "necessary" space would be gobbled.  the `%` approach is (unfortunately) more reliable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know... But I don't know how to check whether the hyphen is last character in the line.